# How to save and retrieve Array of Objects value from Dictionary in Swift iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, dictionary, swift3, nsmutablearray

I am newly to Swift programming. I am developing an app where I have an array of Objects that I need to save it into one Dictionary, means for Dictionary 'Array of Objects' should be my Value and 'ID' should be my Key.

[image]

Here 2 elements contains in my Array, how can I save and retrieve from Dictionary using any unique Key. Please suggest me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by

```
var myDict = Dictionary<String, Any>()
myDict = ["myKey": myArrayObjectName as! VideoRangeInfo]
```

Now you can access you array by use **"myKey"** of dictionary like below,

```
print("My array = \(myDict["myKey"] as! VideoRangeInfo)")
```

**UPDATED:** I think your array is objective c `NSMutableArray` not swift `Array` so

```
var myDic = NSMutableDictionary()
myDic.setObject(myArrayObjectName, forKey: "myKey")
```

And

```
print("My array = \(myDic.object(forKey: "MyKey") as! VideoRangeInfo)")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I applied and getting crash with error "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, " in your second line code. Also there was warning "Cast from 'NSMutableArray' to unrelated type 'VideoRangeInfo' always "

Comment: One more thing @iPatel, when I am fetching array using dictionary by arrayVideoRange = myDic.object(forKey: self.passingFileID) as! NSMutableArray    Then app is crashing bcos of empty dictionary.. Please suggest me where Im doing wrong?

Comment: Add break point and then  print your dictionary look at log and is it empty or not ?

Comment: I have checked, Dictionary is 'nil'. print(myDic.object(forKey: self.passingFileID) as Any))

Comment: try with print(myDic.object(forKey: self.passingFileID) as! NSMutableArray))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159204/discussion-between-user2786-and-ipatel).

Answer (score 0):

One simple approach is:

```
struct VideoRangeInfo {
    var name: String
}

var arrayVideoRange = [
    VideoRangeInfo(name: "Name1"),
    VideoRangeInfo(name: "Name2"),
    VideoRangeInfo(name: "Name3")
]

var dictionary = [String: VideoRangeInfo]()
for obj in arrayVideoRange {
    dictionary.updateValue(obj, forKey: obj.name)
}

print(dictionary["Name1"]!)
print(dictionary["Name2"]!)
print(dictionary["Name3"]!)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lawrence Tan , I tried your code and its working fine for single array of object. But when I am saving array with two Objects for the same key then its giving only one object for the key. And Basically I need to save multiple array of objects for a single Key. Please advise me.

Comment: Hi @user2786, the idea of a dictionary is to store key-pair values where keys are unique. If you want to store multiple array of objects for a single key, what I can think of is something like: 

["singleKey": ["array1": array1, "array2": array2] 

that's dictionaries in dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Saving
    var dictionary =  Int:String

```
dictionary.updateValue(value: self.arrangeVideoInfo[0]!, forKey: 1)
dictionary.updateValue(value: self.arrangeVideoInfo[0]!, forKey: 2)
```

Getting

```
let value1 = dictionary[1] as! VideoRangeInfo
let value2 = dictionary[2] as! VideoRangeInfo
```